# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in a MVC 5 view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Home.Index())">
  <img src="@Url.Content("~/assets/logo.png")" data-at2x="@Url.Content("~/assets/logo@2x.png")"/>
</a>
```

Now and then the application stops and I get the following error:

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

When I click over the image I see 2 messages:

> Encode image in base 64
> Define width and height attributes

This is strange because the error happens only now and then ...

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are using -

```
data-at2x="@Url.Content("~/assets/logo@2x.png")"
```

The MVC 5 razor parser got confused between the Keyword Character `@` and the `@` inside `logo@2x.png`. Either rename it or escape with `@()` like this -

```
data-at2x="@Url.Content("~/assets/logo@("@")2x.png")"
```

It's better you rename it. Will save you a lot of hustle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is saying that `MVC.Home.Index()` sometimes return `null`, which mean that the C# runtime doesn't know which overload of `Url.Action()` to call.

Comment: That does not make a lot of sense ... Does it? I also tried to remove the @ from the image data-at2x path ... Sometimes it solves it sometimes it does not ... So I am not sure that is the problem ... But in fact I do not see any problem on my code